# Modify HTML page dynamically based on number of tag occurrences

Tags: php, jquery, html, content-management-system

I'm looking for a way to modify a HTML Document based on a number of occurring tags. For example

```
<img src="" alt="" />1></a>
    <img src="" alt="" />1></a>
    <img src="" alt="" />1></a>
    <img src="" alt="" />1></a>
```

Must become:

```
<div>
    <img src="" alt="" />1></a>
    <img src="" alt="" />1></a>
    <img src="" alt="" />1></a>
    <img src="" alt="" />1></a>
    </div>"
...
```

That is, for every 4 occurencies of `<img>` there must be a div tag added to the page. For those of you wondering why I can't simply write this - those tags are dinamically generated via other scripts.

Furthermore, only 1 img might be present, or 1231. However, the PHP script must add `<div>` tag at the begginig of every first `<img>`and `</div>` on every 4th and then another `<div>`. If there are only 3,2 or 1 instances, then `</div>` must come after the last one.

Any ideas ?

Please excuse the numerous edits, I was having problem with Firefox not showing the editor.

Comment: Do you control the script that generates the tags?

Comment: Do the `<tag>` always occur serially like above?

Comment: The <tags> always occur serially, however there might be only 1 or 405 instances.

Comment: I do believe your answer can be found here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753786/php-adding-divs-to-a-foreach-loop-every-4-times

Answer (score 1):

```
var tags = $('tag');
var group = new Array();
var i, g = 0;

$.each(tags, function() {
    if(i == 4) {
        g++;
        group[g] = $('<div></div>').appendTo($('body'));
    }
    $(this).appendTo(group[g]);
    i++;
});
```

Or something similar to that

Comment: Sorry, did not read that and just copied it asuming it is PHP. How silly am I loooking now ?