# Is it possible to have 3 div elements and have your loop fill them in order?

Tags: php, laravel

Usually when I loop through a database table records, I put them in 1 div, however, I have been wondering whether it is possible to create 3 divs and then put one record in each div, then start from the first div again and rinse and repeat.

Example of how I've done it so far:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach($albumImages as $albumImage)
    <div class="centeredImage stickyContainer" style="background-image: url('/storage/uploads/albums/{{$albumName}}/{{$albumImage->file_name}}')">
        <a class='specialA' href=''></a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

As you can see in this case, all the records are in the container div.

Example of what I've been thinking about:

```
<div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="col-l"></div>
    <div class="col-c"></div>
    <div class="col-r"></div>
</div>
```

and have the first record go in `col-l`, the second in `col-c`, the third in `col-r` and then start from `col-l` again.

Comment: This can be achieved with the help of Javascript.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. There's tons of ways to do this though (both in PHP and JavaScript, though I would go the PHP route), so it's kind of hard to answer this question in a way everybody is happy.

Comment: Can you tell me what should I be looking for in google in order to find how to do something like that using PHP?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it should get you pointed in the right direction (tip: replace the 4 with 3 and add the classes manually): https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588744/4074200

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you very much!

Comment: Assuming it's just for styling, you're better off using css nth-child selectors. That would also be more useful if you want to make the site responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="flex-grid">
@php($count = 0)
@foreach($albumImages as $albumImage)
    @if ($count % 3 == 0)
        <div class="col-l"></div>
    @elseif($count % 3 == 1)
        <div class="col-c"></div>
    @else
        <div class="col-r"></div>
    @endif
    @php($count++)
@endforeach
</div>
```

You can use this code but I later will update my answer with more good solution

```
@php($count = 0)
@foreach($albumImages as $albumImage)
    @if ($count % 3 == 0)
        @php($albumImages1[] = $albumImage)
    @elseif($count % 3 == 1)
        @php($albumImages2[] = $albumImage)
    @else
        @php($albumImages3[] = $albumImage)
    @endif
    @php($count++)
@endforeach

@if (!empty($albumImages1))
    @foreach($albumImages1 as $albumImage)
    // your logic here
    @endforeach
@endif

@if (!empty($albumImages2))
    @foreach($albumImages2 as $albumImage)
    // your logic here
    @endforeach
@endif

@if (!empty($albumImages3))
    @foreach($albumImages3 as $albumImage)
    // your logic here
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Also you can split three part your initial array make global helper functions.

define global function

```
function split_sequence_by_count ($array, $count) {
    $result = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $result[$i] = [];
    }

    $_count = 0;

    foreach ($array as $current) {
        $index = $_count % 3;
        $result[$index][] = $current;
        $_count++;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

usage in blade

```
@php(list ($albumImages1, $albumImages2, $albumImages3) = split_sequence_by_count($albumImages, 3))

@foreach($albumImages1 as $albumImage)
    // your logic here
@endforeach

@foreach($albumImages2 as $albumImage)
    // your logic here
@endforeach

@foreach($albumImages3 as $albumImage)
    // your logic here
@endforeach
```

Comment: Doesn't that just create the column divs? My goal is to populate them with my database records as well

Comment: That case put your code instead of **<div class="col-*"></div>**

Comment: This is what I don't get, I'm obviously not supposed to create the columns using the loop since this will result in more than 3 columns if I have more than 3 records, so how am I exactly supposed to first create only 3 columns and then populate them with every first, every second and every third record?

Comment: Wow, works like a charm, is it bad that there are so many ifs and foreach?

Comment: Latest 3 foreach need for you. I think I can decrease one foreach in my answer. **@if (!empty($albumImages1))** this conditions never get error when **$albumImages count small then 3**

Comment: @Bobimaru It's not necessarily. This was what I was getting at with my comment that this question isn't really solvable in a way that makes everybody happy. Really custom functionality like this requires really custom code and that just isn't of use to anyone but you. Good answer though!

Comment: I mean in general? I'm actually using this just for styling ( masonry effect for my images ) which I'm sure can be done with JavaScript but have no idea how to do it. This is why I'm wondering if this is not clean/fast code and whether I should keep it or try to figure the JavaScript counterpart.

Comment: @Bobimaru see my updated answer last part it is more good solution then previous solutions

Comment: If I may ask 1 final question. I've been trying to make this work with 4 columns as well using your code, however, I'm not sure what condition to set in the foreach($albumImages as $albumImage) code that separates the images

Comment: that case **@php(list ($albumImages1, $albumImages2, $albumImages3,  $albumImages4) = split_sequence_by_count($albumImages, 4))** That case you need 4 foreach

Comment: Great, thank you very much, you made it so clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) then just run through the array with 2 nested loops. Should be self-explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$people =
[
    'John',
    'Paul',
    'Ringo',
    'George'
];

$i=0;
$classes = ['col-a','col-b','col-c'];
foreach($people as $name) {
    $class = $classes[$i++%3];
    ?>
    <div class='<?=$class?>'>
        <?=$name?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Formatted output:

```
<div class='col-a'>
John    
</div>
<div class='col-b'>
Paul    
</div>
<div class='col-c'>
Ringo    
</div>
<div class='col-a'>
George    
</div>
```

Regarding placing each name in each column (as per your comment), we could wrangle the array format:

```
$classes = ['col-a','col-b','col-c'];
$i=0;
foreach($people as $name)
    $columns[$classes[$i++%3]][] = $name;
?>
<?php foreach($columns as $class=>$column) { ?>
    <div class='<?=$class?>'>
        <?php foreach($column as $name) { ?>
            <div class="name">
                <?=$name?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Formatted output:

```
<div class='col-a'>
   <div class="name">
      John            
   </div>
   <div class="name">
      George            
   </div>
</div>
<div class='col-b'>
   <div class="name">
      Paul            
   </div>
</div>
<div class='col-c'>
   <div class="name">
      Ringo            
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Granted that this needs some translation to your template engine.

Comment: In my case, John and George should be in the same div col-a and there should be no more than 3 divs though.

Comment: @Bobimaru perhaps edit your question, you say: "and have the first record go in col-l, the second in col-c, the third in col-r and then start from col-l again."

Comment: Sorry for misrepresenting my question but by "start from col-l again" I meant have my fourth record go inside the first col-l.

Comment: @Bobimaru added an example.