# Split and loop through a Laravel collection in groups of a specific number

Tags: php, laravel

I have a variable number of Categories (`$categories`) in a Laravel collection, and I need to split them by groups of five, so I can loop through them and display them correctly using Laravel collections, to have a result similar as follow :

```
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat1</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat2</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat3</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat4</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat6</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat7</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat8</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat9</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat10</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat11</a></li>
                                <li class="text-left"><a href="">Cat12</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The categories number is variable, and I need to split this variable number by groups, each group should contain 5 categories, except the last one that will contains what remains. So for example if I have 26 categories, I should have 6 groups, the first 5 groups will contain 5 categories, and the last one will contain the last 1 category.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Adding divs to a foreach loop every 4 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753786/php-adding-divs-to-a-foreach-loop-every-4-times)

Comment: @Remul No duplicate, that has nothing to do with Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Laravel inbuilt split function on a collection

```php
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$groups = $collection->split(3);

$groups->toArray();

// output => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

for more details refer 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-split

Comment: The categories number is variable, and I need to split this variable number by groups, each group should contain 5 categories, except the last one that will contains what remains. So if I have 26 categories, I should have 6 groups, the first 5 groups will contain 5 categories, and the last one will contain the last 1 category.

Answer (score 1):

$collection->chunk(5) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [chunk method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-chunk) like so:

```
@foreach ($categories->chunk(3) as $chunk)
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($chunk as $category)
        <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $category->name }}</div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yes, that what I've posted as an answer for my question. thanks anyways